# Как в django вывести несколько случайных объектов модели?

Tags: html, python, django

У меня есть база данных. Как мне зарандомить (вывести случайные) 3 статьи из нее и вывести их в шаблон?

Вот есть модель статьи models.py. И как мне допустим рандомить 3 статьи и показывать их в html шаблоне через функцию. Вот есть функциия, но я не знаю верна ли она:

```
def RandomArticles(request):
    random_article = Articles.objects.order_by('?')[:3]
    return render(request,'news/posts.html',{'random_article':random_article})


from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отсортиртировать случайным образом средствами базы данных, как у вас в примере, указав `order_by('?')`, но учтите, что это будет работать медленнее, и если будет много статей, придется переделывать под выборку через модуль `random`.

```
Model.object.order_by('?')[:3]
```

> html шаблоне через функцию. вот есть функции я но я незнаю верна ли она

В полне

---

Для вывода в HTML вам нужно передать в контекст список случаных статей. В вашем случае это сделано. И все что вам остается, в файле шаблона `'news/posts.html'` в нужном блоке с помощью тега `for` выводите статьи

```
{% for article in random_article %}
    {{ article.title }}
{% endfor %}
```